# A variable in like then check if image exists

Tags: php, string, variables

I have a variable:

```
$map = $row['map'];
```

I need to check if the link contains "/csgo/maps/$bgimg".

I tried this:

```
 $bgimg = 'map/csgo/' . $map. '.jpg';

 if(!file_exists($bgimg)){ $bgimg = "other_link"; }
```

However, the script returns "other_link" every time.

EDIT:

```
  $topmaps = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `lgsl` where status='1' and map!='-' group by map order by count(map) desc limit 0,5");

    if ( $topmaps == true ){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($topmaps))
    {
    $maps = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `lgsl` where status='1' and `map`='$row[map]'");
    $maps_num = mysql_num_rows($maps);
    if ($maps_num == 1) {$nums = "server";} else {$nums = "servers";}

     $harta = $row['map'];

// CHECK IF BACKGROUND IMAGE EXISTS, IF NOT USE DEFAULT

    $bgimg = 'http://image.www.gametracker.com/images/maps/160x120/csgo/' . $harta . '.jpg';

     if (!file_exists($bgimg)) {
     $bgimg = "http://image.www.gametracker.com/images/maps/160x120/nomap.jpg";
     }
```

This is my entire script... I have a var_dump($bgimg) at the end, which produces:

```
 string(62) "http://image.www.gametracker.com/images/maps/160x120/nomap.jpg" - x5 times
```

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($map);` ?

Comment: You have `/csgo/maps/$bgimg` and `'map/csgo/' . $map. '.jpg';`. Which order is `csgo` and `map`/`maps`?

Comment: string(11) "fy_buzzkill" string(12) "cs_backalley" string(5) "world" string(10) "de_inferno" string(25) "ze_lotr_mines_of_moria_p2"   .... @Sean , actualy is a like from gametracker and looks like this http://image.www.gametracker.com/images/maps/160x120/csgo/MAP.jpg

Comment: so now you have a 3rd format `maps/160x120/csgo/MAP.jpg`, that does not match the other 2. Try `var_dump($bgimg)` and check in your browser if the pathway to the file is correct.

Comment: hmmm, it returns me 5 time (i have a desc limit in query), the same link : "other_link"... (@Sean)

Comment: Well, then that tells you either (1) those files don't exist, or (2) your pathway and/or link to the file is incorrect. We can't debug either of those for you with the code that you provided.

Comment: `http://image.www.gametracker.com` looks to be an invalid url. I would think either remove `image` or `www`.

Comment: you want to `var_dump($bgimg)` before `if (!file_exists($bgimg))`, not after, as you want the initial setting of `$bgimg = 'http://image.www.gametracker.com/images/maps/160x120/csgo/' . $harta . '.jpg';`. Then check to see if that is a valid link.

Comment: Does file_exists work with URLs? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: I solved this problem.. I used GetImageSize(); and now works with links !:) It's fine.